# What is the output of option 'n' for a grep on a device?

Tags: linux, grep

If I do this:

> grep -a -n 'test' /dev/sdb10

It will search on the device sdb10 at binary level for a string 'test'. I can see the output of 'n' option, but what does it represent? Is the device treated as a single file?

My objective is to pinpoint the location of a file on the device so I can 'dd' a section of the drive.

Comment: Maybe 'n' is the line number in term of 'line feed' characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-a` switch (`--text`) does treat binary files as if they were text files and the device file `/dev/sdb10` is always treated as if it were an actual file, but the `-n` switch (`--line-number`) only prints line numbers, which is rather useless in this case. The `-b` switch (`--byte-offset`) will help you find the location of the string.

To avoid echoing a lot of non-printable characters as well, you can use it in combination with the `-o` switch (`--only-matching`).

Example:

```
sudo grep -abo test /dev/sdb10
```